# Ruby On Rails: suggested gems / development stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, stack

I'm new to **RoR** development and I'm searching for suggestion for finding *best community gems*.

E.g. for authentication/authorization? Is devise a good component? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Is there any gem for produce a richer gui in views with easy?

In few words, an experienced RoR developer what gems he installs after creating a new app?

Regards,
Giacomo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always basic in nearly all my apps.

```
gem 'devise'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.1"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "devise_mailchimp"

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.11'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11"
gem 'thin'
```

and more. You can also visit http://railscasts.com/ you will get more ideas there.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question, [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is a great resource for finding Ruby/Rails projects (both new and old) as well as comparing the relative popularity of gems providing similar solutions. While the active development culture behind Ruby is empowering for developers accustomed to reading and writing Ruby, I think many newer developers get overwhelmed with all the options.

With that in mind, for someone who is just beginning Ruby/Rails development, I'd suggest either rolling your own authorization/authentication system or following a tutorial that explains the process. You can find a great tutorial explaining the basic structure of a User model including authentication in [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#top)

Likewise, understanding that Rails Views can be as simple as combining regular, old HTML, CSS, and Javascript with some Ruby variables is valuable without depending on the magic of something like Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, tutorial you suggested is very interesting... Maybe I've something new to read this weekend! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Yes devise is very good gem with a lots of options and flexible authentications .

see this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications

For gui in views you can use bootstrap twitter gem. It is easy and you can quickly build your view.

The gem installed by developers is depend on their need. there are more tah 1300 gem available right now...

Keep coding.

Comment: Thank you, I also think that Devise could help auth tasks.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me a lot was viewing a bunch of [Railcasts](http://railscasts.com/). You'll get a good overview of gems you might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [rails style guides](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) from bbatsov, it's a community-driven guide, there are many practices that people used every day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my gemfile

you can also look into [ruby-toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/)

[image]

[image]